# Poisson distribution question, solving for time until event occurs.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poissons-equation, gamma-distribution

I've got this lengthy question that I'm really struggling with, I'd appreciate all help i can get.

---

"The number of customers Y arriving at a walk-in shop in the first t minutes after it opens doors [i.e time interval (0,t)] on any particular day follows a poisson distribution with mean $\lambda t$.
[the parameter $\lambda$ is the rate of arrivals per unit time and $t$ is the length of time period, so $\lambda t$ represents the mean of number of customers arriving in the interval of length $t$.

a) Let the random variable $T$ denote the time (in minutes) until the arrival of the first customer. Determine the probability density function of $T$.
[Hint: if $T>a$, then no customers have arrived in the time period (0,a).]

b) Let the random variable $U$ be the time until the arrival of the second customer. Show that $U$ has a gamma distribution with $\alpha = 2$ and $\beta=1/\lambda$

c) Let the random variable $W$ be the time until the arrival of the $k$th customer. Show that $W$ has a gamma distribution with $\alpha=k$ and $\beta=1/\lambda$.

---

I'm assuming that for part a, i need to solve $P(Y \le 1)=P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)$ for
$P(Y=y)=$ $(\lambda t)^y e^{-\lambda t} \over y!$
and then solve for $t$ from there, but i'm not really sure.

as for part b and c, I'm not really sure, as they both seem to depend on the solving the first part.

I know it's a lengthy question, and it'd take some time to get it solved.

All the help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: You aren't using the given hint in your attempt of part a). Reconsider: if $T>a$ then no customers arrived in $(0,a)$, thus $Y_a=0$ (I use the subscript to signify which time interval is of concern). So, $P(T>a)=P(Y_a=0)=...$, can you finish?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29, thanks for the reply... I started following your suggestion and I got as far as $P(Y_a =0)= e^({-\lambda t)}$  ....  i'm not sure how that will return me $T$

Comment: remember you are after the PDF of $T$. You just obtained $P(T>t)=e^{-\lambda t}$ (replacing $a$ with $t$, as you did). Now use the fact that the CDF $F_T(t)=P(T\leq t)=1-P(T>t)$. Substitute your expression for $P(T>t)$ and use the fact that the derivative of the CDF is equal to the PDF: $F_T'(t)=f_T(t)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29, that's great... i ended up at $f_T (t)= \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ .... which i believe is the end result for part a... what is the way to approach part b and c? I'm really grateful to your help

Comment: indeed, thus you've proven the waiting time until the first arrival of a Poisson process is exponentially distributed! Part b) and c) take a little more work than i'm willing to outline in comments but the idea is the same. To get you started, note that if $T_j >t$ (where $T_j$ is the time until the $j$-th customer) then $N_t \leq j-1$, thus their probabilities... when I get out of work I may write a full answer for b) and c) if youre still stuck or if it hasn't been answered yet. Good luck :)

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 please do so, I got stuck in my every attempt, as I almost have no experience with gamma function/distribution... it's getting pretty late here, I'll look to your answer first thing in the morning.... thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part $a)$ was addressed in the comments and $b)$ is a special case of $c)$ which you can verify after seeing the general idea, I only present hints for $c)$.

Again, note that if $T_j$ is the time until the $j$-th customer arrives, then $T_j >t $ if and only if $N_t < j$. Thus, $P(T_j >t)=P(N_t \leq j-1)$. Writing as before, we have $F_{T_j}(t)=1-P(N_t \leq j-1)$. But this is equal to
$$1-e^{-\lambda t}\left(1+\lambda t+\frac1{2!}(\lambda t)^2+\dotsc +\frac1{(j-1)!}(\lambda t)^{j-1}\right).$$

Differentiate, with respect to $t$, the above expression to get $f_{T_j}(t)=\frac{\lambda^j}{(j-1)!}t^{j-1}e^{-\lambda t}$ and recognize this is the PDF of r.v. with Gamma distribution,
$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)\beta^\alpha} t^{\alpha-1}e^{- t/\beta}$, where $\alpha=j$, and $\beta=1/\lambda$, QED.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I think it worked out well in the end and proved correctly.... there's only one thing I wanted to ask about, I reckon you had a typo that should've been $F_{T_j}(t)=1-P(N_t \leq j-1)$ instead of $\le$... it worked out pretty well using $<$... thanks again for the massive help... cheers

Comment: @suspectzero no problem. It is not a typo. If the time until the $j$th customer is strictly greater than $t$, i.e. $T_j>t$ then the number of customers at time $t$ is strictly less than $j$, i.e. $N_t <j$ because the $j$th customer has not arrived yet. Thus, since $N_t$ takes non-negative integer values, the number of customers is at most $j-1$, i.e. $N_t \leq j-1$. Note if $X$ is a discrete r.v. and $P(X=k)\neq 0$ then, $P(X\leq k) -P(X<k)=P(X=k) \neq 0$, so you must be careful with inequality signs as they'll change the value of the cdf.